# Error al poner "python manage.py makemigrations"

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

Lo que quería hacer era montar mi primer base de datos de postgresql y cuando quise poner `python manage.py makemigrations` me dio el error de abajo:

```
ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'

NAME': 'articulosclientes'

USER': 'postgres'

PASSWORD': 'Dogchog123'

HOST':'127.0.0.1'

DATABASE_PORT':'52269'
```

Si necesitan mas datos solo díganmelo y se los paso

PD: tuve problemas para instalar `psycopg2`, pero pude, díganme si también el problema puede ser ese

```
PS C:\Users\RedTrox\Desktop\ProyectosDjango\TiendaOnline> python manage.py makemigrations

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\RedTrox\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\RedTrox\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\RedTrox\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 197, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\RedTrox\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\RedTrox\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 185, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\RedTrox\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\RedTrox\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\RedTrox\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\RedTrox\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\RedTrox\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\RedTrox\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\RedTrox\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemigrations.py", line 101, in handle
    loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "C:\Users\RedTrox\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 283, in check_consistent_history
    applied = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\RedTrox\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 76, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "C:\Users\RedTrox\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 56, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
  File "C:\Users\RedTrox\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\RedTrox\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 260, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "C:\Users\RedTrox\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 236, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\RedTrox\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\RedTrox\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\RedTrox\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\RedTrox\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\RedTrox\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\RedTrox\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 197, in 




connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\RedTrox\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\RedTrox\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 185, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\RedTrox\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError
```

Comment: Hola. ¿Has podido conectarte con algún cliente a tu base de datos con esos parámetros que has mencionado para probar la conexión en sí? Por cierto, es recomendable no publicar nunca ninguna contraseña, aunque sea de un entorno de pruebas.

Comment: Si primero debes estar seguro que tienes postgres corriendo en local. después intenta conectarse usando un comando como: $ psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U nombre_de_usuario -d nombre_de_base_de_datos    y debe pedirte la contraseña y conectarte, el comando /l te debe listar las base de datos disponibles.

Comment: En que sistema operativo esta instalado postgress, ¿Has podido conectarte con tu base de dato postgress?,   instálate pgAdmin y observa si funciona bien la conexión en tu base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

faltan las comas correspondientes, y asegúrate de que el nombre es igual tanto en la base de datos como en el settings, y recuerda que es sensible a las minúsculas y mayúsculas

ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',

NAME': 'articulosclientes',

USER': 'postgres',

PASSWORD': 'Dogchog123',

HOST':'127.0.0.1',

DATABASE_PORT':'52269',